# Make a custom field clickable

Tags: fields

I have an external object and I want to make custom field clickable to the record instead of the salesforce standard name field. I found out lot of alternates like creating a formula field and making it clickable. But, the issue here is external objects are not provided with the flexibility of creating a formula fields. 
Please let me know your thoughts and any solutions.